# Given the nth Partial Sum, write a formula for $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $S_n = \frac{n+1}{2n+5}$, the n-th partial sum of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ , write a rule for $a_n$.

Now,

$$a_n = S_n - S_{n-1} = \frac{n+1}{2n+5} - \frac{n}{2n+3}=\frac{3}{(2n+5)(2n+3)}$$

I am fairly certain I have solved the problem correctly but am confused about something.

Why is it that (given the $S_n$ formula) $S_1 = \frac{(1+1)}{2(1)+5} = \frac{2}{7}$ but $a_1 = \frac{3}{(2+5)(2+3)}=\frac{3}{35}$?

My understanding would be that $S_1 = a_1$ but that isn't true here. What am I missing?

Comment: $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$ for $n > 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you check that formula for $S_n$ , $S_0=\frac{1}{5}\neq 0$ but when you apply the deduced formula for $a_1$, what you derived is from $a_1=S_1-S_0$, that is why it fails for $a_1$. Namely, $S_1\neq a_1$

Comment: The way your name fits my question is amusing... As I understand, $S_0 = 0$  because it is the sum of "nothing". Is that a viable way to think about it?

Comment: But if you set $n=0$ to the formula of $S_n$, you found $S_0=1/5\neq 0$, that's why it fails for $a_1$, and you have to start to use that formula from $a_2$ @blacknapkins7

Comment: Why must $S_0 = 0$?

Comment: Intuitively, $S_0$ means add nothing. @blacknapkins7